# Was I awarded the Vox Populi badge due to a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was just notified that I received the [Vox Populi](https://superuser.com/badges/110/vox-populi) badge on Super User, which is apparently awarded for voting 40 times in a single day.  I don't vote nearly that often (I average about vote every 2 days), so I can't fathom that I ever made 40 votes in a single day.  Especially not yesterday or today, since I did almost nothing at all on the site either of those days.

Is there a bug in how [Vox Populi](https://superuser.com/badges/110/vox-populi) is calculated that caused it to be awarded to me in error?

Comment: I just got it on Fitness as well, where I know for sure that I've never voted on 40 posts in one day

Comment: +1 this just happened to me

Answer (score 4):

We just deployed a change that affects the voting badges.  This is why you see a number of these badges being awarded.

For more information about this change, you can see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123048/140548).

Note that there is a bug with Vox Populi only that is awarding too many of them, beyond the expected more for retroactive awards, and a fix is being deployed now.  The erroneous awards there will be cleaned up shortly.

Comment: It appears that Vox Populi has now been removed from my list of awarded badges, so it seems like the fix worked.